# Are the servers overloaded?

Tags: installation

Download speeds plummet down to zero after trying to download either zip files or the installers for the current version.
EDIT: Downloading via Steam worked, thanks.

Comment: Looks that way, can't download here either

Comment: Yes, a lot of people are currently downloading the new version because of the official release. You can try to download via Steam, might be faster.

Comment: same when trying to download older versions :( my steam version ungraded to 2.8 but I am not ready for it